# VSCode - Changing the debug console typing color

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm trying to change the typing text color for the theme I'm using in the debug console. I can't find which setting in the [documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/theme-color#integrated-terminal-colors) corresponds to the text highlighted in the screenshot. What is the name of the setting to change this color?

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't look like there is a setting for changing this.

Comment: That should be picking up your syntax colors.

Comment: Thanks. Fixed it by updating the terminal syntax colors.